# IntelliJ does not recognize symbols: Gradle, Scala, AWS

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea

I'm using Gradle to build something for AWS with Scala.  In my source file I have this:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.{Context => LambdaContext}
```

in my build.gradle file, I have this:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.1.0'
```

the code builds fine and works, but IntelliJ keeps giving me an error that "Context" is ambiguous, and the choices it gives do not include a class in the AWS library.  I'm getting this for all of the AWS libraries I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding this:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

to build.gradle.